# Keep first visible item in UICollectionView after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I searched for an answer in other StackOverflow questions, but I couldn't find any solution to the following issue:

I'm trying to use a UICollectionView with a flow layout (vertical) and make the item size depend on the screen size (it should leverage the width of the iPad or even the width of the iPhone in landscape orientation).

I want to make the UICollectionView display just one column of items on a portrait oriented iPhone, but 2 on a landscape oriented iPhone. And of course, make it generic so that it could also display more columns if more horizontal room is available, such as in the iPad.

To achieve this behavior, I did the following:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    NSInteger columns = 1 + ((NSInteger)(CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame) - layout.sectionInset.left - layout.sectionInset.right + layout.minimumInteritemSpacing)) / ((NSInteger)(layout.minimumInteritemSpacing + 300.0 + 1.0));
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake((CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame) - layout.sectionInset.left - layout.sectionInset.right - ((columns - 1) * layout.minimumInteritemSpacing)) / columns, layout.itemSize.height);

    [layout invalidateLayout];
 }
```

This works pretty good and when I rotate my phone, I can see the layout displaying two columns instead of just one.

But I cannot make the UICollectionView keep the first visible item after the rotation, as it is setting the content offset to whatever it was prior the rotation. As the layout changed and now the UICollectionView displays two columns on landscape, this new content offset should have a new value, that corresponds to the same item, but under a new layout.

I tried using the following snippet, but I did not manage to get it working:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    NSIndexPath *firstAddShowCellIndexPath = [[[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSIndexPath *ip1 = obj1;
        NSIndexPath *ip2 = obj2;
        return [ip1 compare:ip2];
    }] firstObject];

    if (firstAddShowCellIndexPath) {
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:firstAddShowCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I suspect the UICollectionView is trying to handle the content offset during the rotation, so I even tried using `dispatch_after` or `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, but although it did work, it set the content offset to late, after rotation finished, giving a really bad user experience.

Any ideas?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

Add this instead of `willRotation` method

```
#pragma mark - Rotation
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Just as an example this is my quick code for making **two** columns before and after rotation, etc

```
#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    int width = roundf(self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 2.0) - 15;
    int height = roundf(width * 0.8);
    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIEdgeInsets new = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    return new;
}
```